# Spring MVC Project - Reading CSV File - HTTP Status 500 - data.csv (Access is denied)

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-mvc, csv

I am trying to use Spring Tool Suite to read in a csv file and print its output to the console but it gives me a HTTP Status 500 - data.csv (Access is denied). I have added the maven dependency file opencsv which is this in my pom.xml file:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.sf.opencsv</groupId>
    <artifactId>opencsv</artifactId>
    <version>2.3</version>
</dependency>
```

And the whole code in my HomeController is:

```
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Locale;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.context.request.WebRequest;

import au.com.bytecode.opencsv.CSVReader;

/**
 * Handles requests for the application home page.
 */
@Controller
public class HomeController {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(HomeController.class);



    /**
     * Simply selects the home view to render by returning its name.
     * @throws Exception 
     */
    @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String home(Locale locale, Model model) throws Exception {
        logger.info("Welcome home! The client locale is {}.", locale);

        CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(new FileReader("data.csv"));
        String [] nextLine;
        while ((nextLine = reader.readNext()) != null) {
            // nextLine[] is an array of values from the line
            System.out.println(nextLine[0] + nextLine[1] + "etc...");
        }

        Date date = new Date();
        DateFormat dateFormat = DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance(DateFormat.LONG, DateFormat.LONG, locale);

        String formattedDate = dateFormat.format(date);

        model.addAttribute("serverTime", formattedDate );

        return "home";
    }


    @RequestMapping(value = "/c_Outage", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String c_outage(HttpSession session, WebRequest request, Model model) {
       return "currentO";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/f_Outage", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String f_outage(HttpSession session, WebRequest request, Model model) {
       return "futureO";
    }
}
```

And the console stacktrace is:

```
type Exception report

message data.csv (Access is denied)

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception 

java.io.FileNotFoundException: data.csv (Access is denied)
    java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
    java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
    java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
    java.io.FileReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
    edu.byuh.beginningSrping.HomeController.home(HomeController.java:40)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:213)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:126)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:96)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:617)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:578)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:80)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:923)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:852)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:778)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)


note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache Tomcat/7.0.47 logs.
```

I have dragged and dropped my data.csv in the project. And if I removed this block of code which is in my HomeController:

```
CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(new FileReader("data.csv"));
            String [] nextLine;
            while ((nextLine = reader.readNext()) != null) {
                // nextLine[] is an array of values from the line
                System.out.println(nextLine[0] + nextLine[1] + "etc...");
            }
```

I would be able to have my page show up correctly. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put your `data.csv` file inside `WEB-INF` directory and change the code for the following.

```
    /**
     * Simply selects the home view to render by returning its name.
     * @throws Exception 
     */
    @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String home(Locale locale, Model model, HttpServletRequest req) throws Exception {
        logger.info("Welcome home! The client locale is {}.", locale);

        CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(new FileReader(req.getServletContext().getRealPath("/WEB-INF")+"/data.csv"));
        String [] nextLine;
        while ((nextLine = reader.readNext()) != null) {
            // nextLine[] is an array of values from the line
            System.out.println(nextLine[0] + nextLine[1] + "etc...");
        }

        Date date = new Date();
        DateFormat dateFormat = DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance(DateFormat.LONG, DateFormat.LONG, locale);

        String formattedDate = dateFormat.format(date);

        model.addAttribute("serverTime", formattedDate );

        return "home";
    }
```